Is there a way to write a custom assert method recognized by type checkers?
I have a custom logging class that notably handles logging of warnings and errors that happen at runtime. I would like to also be able to log assertion failures without being too intrusive by defining a custom assert function that performs the assertion and logs an error message if it failed.
This seemed easy to do, but static type checkers like PyLance do not consider the function as the built-in assert. Consider this minimal example:
def my_assert(condition: bool, msg: str):
    if not condition:
        logger.error(msg)
        raise AssertionError(msg)

I would then expect to be able to use this method as the built-in assert without being annoyed by "Operator '+' not supported for 'None'" type of stuff.
def add_one(a: int | None) -> int:
    my_assert(a is not None, "a is None")
    return a + 1  # Pylance lints this as being possibly None

Is there a way to indicate to type checkers that this is a false positive, and it should be treated as an assert? Otherwise, is there a better way to do this while preserving a lightweight notation?

What if you did the logging in a top-level try...except AssertionError, rather than in a lower level helper function?  Then the inner code can use a regular old assert with all the convenience that provides.

You're basically looking for a one-liner (i.e. a simple statement) which performs type-narrowing on a type.
Python only allows user-defined type-narrowing callbacks callbacks of the format
Callable[[argument to narrow type of, <any other arguments> ...], <narrowed type>]

and type-narrowing can only happen in the calling context with asserts or if...elif...else-checks. So, you'll have to fit your custom log-then-assert function into this format. Something like the following will work on not Nones (Pyright Playground):
import typing as t
from logging import getLogger

T = t.TypeVar("T")
logger = getLogger()

def check_type(arg: T | None, condition: bool, msg: str) -> t.TypeGuard[T]:
    if not condition:
        logger.error(msg)
        raise AssertionError(msg)
    return True

def add_one(a: int | None) -> int:
    assert check_type(a, a is not None, "a is None")
    reveal_type(a)  # int
    return a + 1

For more general cases, I believe that you'll have to bind the undesirable types into a class. Something like this (Pyright Playground):
Other = t.TypeVar("Other")

class not_(t.Generic[Other]):
    @classmethod
    def check_type(cls, arg: T | Other, condition: bool, msg: str) -> t.TypeGuard[T]:
        if not condition:
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AssertionError(msg)
        return True

def add_one(a: int | str) -> int:
    assert not_[str].check_type(a, type(a) is not str, "a is str")
    reveal_type(a)  # int
    return a + 1


Thank you for the answer, this should indeed solve my issue as I believe type checkers don't handle non-type related asserts anyway
